# can sessions variables be altered by the user in their browser

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to learn more on sessions and I was wondering if checking if a specific session is set is enough to prevent a user from accessing a webpage without having logged in first

example:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['jfn7^j3#$jnj;7gs!~']))
{
header('location:abc.php');
}
```

or is there a way this can be bypassed

And secondly if I initialize a session variable once  a user has successfully logged in
example:

```
$_SESSION['username']='MAX';
```

Is there a way the user can change the value of the set $_SESSION['username'] on their browser

Comment: no. the user cannot change the value of a `$_SESSION` variable from their browser, unless there code which specifically lets them do so (or a vulnerability of some kind). The short answer is "no"

Comment: So there's no need to use random session variable names like that. Session variables only exist on the server, the client never sees them.

Comment: Yes, they can. Session variables are stored as cookies. If there is an XSS with injected Javascript code session variables can be stolen resulting in impersonation and perhaps CSRF. There are ways to execute Javascript code in web consoles for web browsers, allowing anything Javascript can do to cookies happening. Finally if a hacker gets access to your machine they can also steal/manipulate cookies (and your saved passwords!) as they please. Client side code and data is free game basically.

Comment: I'm really confused , one of you is saying session variables is stored in the server while another is saying session variables is stored in browser cookies. Can someone please clarify this

Comment: Actually, what Steve Mucci has said is generally **incorrect.**  Most commonly, the only thing that's stored on the client-side is a "cookie value" which is actually random.  All of the session-values are stored, in some way, on the server side, indexed by that random value.